# How to enable Android CameraX Vendor extensions?

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I'm trying to build a camera app based on CameraX and want to enable Bokeh (Blur) effect for the camera preview. This might be done by CameraX extensions, but how to enable them?

I've read the article about Vendor extensions at [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/vendor-extensions). I've tried to reuse their approach, but classes shown at the example are not included at CameraX `alpha-02`

```
import androidx.camera.extensions.BokehExtender;

void onCreate() {
    // Create a Builder same as in normal workflow.
    ImageCaptureConfig.Builder builder = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder();

    // Create a Extender object which can be used to apply extension
    // configurations.
    BokehImageCaptureExtender bokehImageCapture = new
            BokehImageCaptureExtender(builder);

    // Query if extension is available (optional).
    if (bokehImageCapture.isExtensionAvailable()) {
        // Enable the extension if available.
        bokehImageCapture.enableExtension();
    }

    // Finish constructing configuration with the same flow as when not using
    // extensions.
    ImageCaptureConfig config = builder.build();
    ImageCapture useCase = new ImageCapture(config);
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, useCase);
}
```

I expected that `BokehImageCaptureExtender` will be imported, but looks like it's still not provided. And the whole package `androidx.camera.extensions` is missing.

This classes could be found at the official [AndroidX git repository](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/camera/extensions/src/main/java/androidx/camera/extensions) but it's hard to setup it without importing the full AndroidX project.

Answer (score 1):

Android CameraX extensions are only present in version: **"1.0.0-alpha01"**.

Downgrade your camera version:
//Camera Jetpack Library

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:$camerax_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noted editing your question and looking [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/vendor-extensions#java) take the **Code Sample** you showed is **Java**, but you put **Kotlin** as identifier. Make sure that you are using the correct language. This might be the problem.

This is the **Kotlin** sample from [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/vendor-extensions#kotlin):

```
import androidx.camera.extensions.BokehExtender

fun onCreate() {
    // Create a Builder same as in normal workflow.
    val builder = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()

    // Create a Extender object which can be used to apply extension
    // configurations.
    val bokehImageCapture = BokehImageCaptureExtender.create(builder)

    // Query if extension is available (optional).
    if (bokehImageCapture.isExtensionAvailable()) {
        // Enable the extension if available.
        bokehImageCapture.enableExtension()
    }

    // Finish constructing configuration with the same flow as when not using
    // extensions.
    val config = builder.build()
    val useCase = ImageCapture(config)
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, useCase)
}
```

This is the **Java** sample from [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/vendor-extensions#java):

```java
import androidx.camera.extensions.BokehExtender;

void onCreate() {
    // Create a Builder same as in normal workflow.
    ImageCaptureConfig.Builder builder = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder();

    // Create a Extender object which can be used to apply extension
    // configurations.
    BokehImageCaptureExtender bokehImageCapture = new
            BokehImageCaptureExtender(builder);

    // Query if extension is available (optional).
    if (bokehImageCapture.isExtensionAvailable()) {
        // Enable the extension if available.
        bokehImageCapture.enableExtension();
    }

    // Finish constructing configuration with the same flow as when not using
    // extensions.
    ImageCaptureConfig config = builder.build();
    ImageCapture useCase = new ImageCapture(config);
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, useCase);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that there is no such package as `androidx.camera.extensions`

Answer (score 0):

Extension are still not available on google maven 
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Refer to this thread,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177147/11861734