# Cant import vendor extensions of CameraX

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

I've been trying to use the new CameraX library. Everything else works fine but I'm unable to import the vendor extension just like they say in the documentation.

https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/vendor-extensions

```
import androidx.camera.extensions.BokehExtender;
```

This shows "Cant resolve symbol extensions"

Here's my build.gradle

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is possible that the documentation is ahead of the releases, and that class is not yet available.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use camera-extensions library yet.
However, changes to release it were committed on July 15.
We may be able to use it in the next version.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/8289a725a508a5b43da450e596612f9cb8c5624b%5E%21/#F1

If you just want to try it, you can try `Testing modified AndroidX Libraries to in your App`.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev

Answer (score 0):

Please add gradle dependency for the vendor extensions:

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha01"
```